# If $G$ is a group of even order, prove it has an element $a\neq e$ satisfying $a^2=e$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups

If $G$ is a group of even order, prove it has an element $a \neq e$ satisfying $a^2 = e$.

My proof:

Let $|G| = 2n$. Since $G$ is finite, there exists, $a \in G$ such that $a^p = e$ and by Lagrange's Theorem, p divides 2n. By Euclid's lemma, since p does not divide 2, p divides n. Let $n = pk$. Hence, $(a^n)^2 = (a^{pk})^2 = ((a^p)^k)^2 = (e^k)^2 = e$. Therefore, $a^n$ is an element that satisfy the condition.

Is my solution OK?

For this problem, I am just wondering how I can solve this problem without using Lagrange's Theorem, as this problem is an exercise before the Lagrange's Theorem was taught.

Comment: I don't see any problem.

Comment: You must exclude that $a^n = e$.

Comment: Check the list of Related questions (on the right), and you'll find some insights.

Comment: @AlexR what do you mean by i must exclude $a^n = e$

Comment: @user136266 If $a^n = e$, you only show $e^2 = e$ in a way.

Comment: @user136266 [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188519/prove-that-any-finite-group-g-of-even-order-contains-an-element-of-order-2?rq=1) is a correct proof if the statement.

Comment: @AlexR if $a^n = e$, it doesn't mean that $a = e$, does it?

Comment: @user136266 But you say "$a^n$ is an element that satisfies the condition", implying $a^n \ne e$ without first ruling out $a^n = e$.

Comment: @AlexR I think you (should) mean that the case $\;a=e\;$ must be ruled out, otherwise there is no proof. Also, $\;a=e=e^1=e\;$ and indeed $\;1\mid 2\;$, and the OP's proof falls apart.

Comment: @Timbuc $a^n = e$ already destroys the proof, wich is especially the case for $a=e$.

Comment: This whole argument is a result of user13626 using $a$ in two roles: the $a$ of the first sentence ("prove it has an element $a \ne e...$") is different from the $a$ in the proof ("there exists, $a \in G...$"). You should say "Take any $x \in G$ such that $x^n \ne e$. Then there exists $p \in \mathbb N$ such that..." Then you end up choosing $a=x^n$. You also have to show that there exists such an $x$ (with $x^n \ne e$).

Comment: $a^n$ has order 1, because it is always $e$.

Comment: I am a little puzzled by what $p$ is supposed to be. Here is something along these lines. Start by taking a non-trivial element $g\in G$ which has order dividing $2n$. If its order $d$ is even then $g^{d/2}$ has order 2. Otherwise its order is odd so $d=pd'$ where $p$ is an odd prime. But now I don't see how to go further. I think the proofs given by other people are the way to go. Of course the general version for a prime dividing $|G|$ is Cauchy's Theorem and there are many proofs.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The following is perhaps one of most simple proofs:

Pair up **if possible** each element of $\;G\;$ with its inverse, and observe that

$$g^2\neq e\iff g\neq g^{-1}\iff \;\text{there exists the pair}\;\;(g, g^{-1})$$

Now, there is one element that has no pairing: the unit $\;e\;$ (since indeed $\;e=e^{-1}\iff e^2=e$), so since the number of elements of $\;G\;$ is even there **must** be at least one element *more*, say $\;e\neq a\in G\;$ ,  without a pairing, and thus $\;a=a^{-1}\iff a^2=e\;$

Comment: @user136266 Who said anything about "only" two such elements? The above proves that besides the unit $\;e\;$ there **must** be another element with $\;a^2=e\;$, since the number of elements in $\;G\;$ is even. In fact, the above shows that under the conditions of the problem, there is always an *odd* number of non-unit elements which have order two.

Comment: Very neat! ${}{}$

Answer (score 13):

This is not a strict proof, but you may find it helpful when you want proof without Lagrange's theorem:

We have that for every $g\in G$ there a unique $g^{-1} \in G$ such that $gg^{-1}=e$.
If you suppose that there is no $a \in G$ such that $a^2=e$, so that $a=a^{-1}$ (i.e. there is no self-inverse element), then for every $x\neq e$ in $G$ we can assign unique $y\in G$ such that $xy=e$. So the set of pairs of elements that are inverses to each other form a partition for $G$.

But then $|G|$ is odd since $e$ is only self-inverse element.

Comment: You need to exclude the case $p = n$ also (in the second argument).

Comment: If $p$ is the order of $a$ then $a^n = a^{pk} = e^k = e$. $a^n$ will never be the required element.

Comment: Smallest counter-example is any element of order $3$ in $(\mathbb Z_{12}, +)$.

Comment: "Then either $p$ divides $2$ or it doesn't since $2$ is a prime": In my universe, "either $p$ divides $n$ or it doesn't" is true for composite $n$ too :-)

Comment: @AlexR yep I wasn't aware of that when I was writing. I cannot think of a way to refine this style of proof (proving existence by finding one) to make it true unfortunately :(

Comment: @TonyK Haha true I must have said that "either $p$ divides $2$ or $n$ since $2$ is a prime

Comment: @user160738 Since there is already an accepted answer and the original proof is unsalvagable, I suggest you delete the bottom part your answer and undelete it once you found a construction wich actually works.

Comment: @AlexR Done it!