# Isomorphisms of the Monster Group

Tags: group-theory

So I was given the fact that the Monster Group is a non abelian group of order $2^{46} · 3^{20} · 5^9 · 7^6 · 11^2 · 13^3 · 17 · 19 · 23 · 29 · 31 · 41 · 47 · 59 · 71$.

But what I do not quite understand is how to show that there is a subgroup of this Monster isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z_2}$.

Any suggestions will be helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: A subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}?$ If am not wrong this is not possible.

Comment: Could you clarify what "large" order means, as you are using it?  The term "large" is relative.

Comment: By large I just meant that it is a Large number. (Did not want to type it out the first time around.)

Comment: Please check that I TeXified the order correctly. Surely the list of factors was supposed to be powers of primes. Also, the question is still non-sensical given that the Monster is finite.

Comment: To give a helpful answer we need to know what you know about groups? If this is your first course in groups, then the question makes sense as an exercise from a slightly naughty teacher. If you are more than a few months into studying groups, then the question does not IMO make any sense.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This is my first course in Group Theory.

Comment: In that case I hazard a guess that the intended solution is to imitate the argument [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/42034/11619). See e.g. Arturo Magidin's answer.

Comment: I am tempted to close this as a duplicate of one of the linked questions, because that same argument works for the Monster. Vote/comment, please.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, you are right. The question really has nothing to do with the monster.  Any finite group of even order will do, and your link is the right one (I saw it only after my answer, I am sorry). So I don't mind closing.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Any finite group of even order contains an element of order $2$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111868/if-g-is-a-group-of-even-order-prove-it-has-an-element-a-neq-e-satisfying-a), or use Cauchy's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider two cases, one in which the order is finite, one for which the order is infinite, recalling that any element generates a cyclic group whose size is equal to the order of the element.

Comment: Order of what?
I know the order of the Monster Group is large.  Am I supposed to find a subgroup of finite order and then a subgroup of infinite order from the Monster Group?

Comment: Order of the Monster Group, yes.

Comment: Are you aware that the monster group is finite?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yes, I am aware of it, that's why I sense that trying to produce an subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ is impossible, but I am not completely convinced that this is so for $\mathbb{Z_2}$

Comment: Quarternion: I think @Tobias was directing his comment to address this answer and its author, and not you!