# If G is a finite group of even order then G contains an element $a\neq e$ such that $a^2=e$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

For this problem, I'd like to know how I can solve this problem using Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: You can't solve it using Lagrange's theorem. Lagrange's theorem limits the possible subgroups and elements you can have, but it doesn't say anything about whether anything actually exists. Sylow's first theorem and _then_ Lagrange's theorem would help, but that's probably overkill.

Comment: One feature of finite groups is that you can count the elements - so when finiteness is specified, counting arguments come into the frame as a strategy.

Comment: This question has really many duplicates on this site, e.g., also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188519/prove-that-any-finite-group-g-of-even-order-contains-an-element-of-order-2?rq=1). Please have a look before posting your question.