# Let $G$ be a group of even order. Define $t(G)$ to be the set $\{ g \in G\mid g\neq g^{-1}\}$. Show that $t(G)$ has an even number of elements.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be a group of even order. Define $t(G)$ to be the set $\{g\in G\mid  g\neq g^{-1}\}$. Show that $t(G)$ has an even number of elements.

I saw there are many solutions related to this question but I want to verify whether my solution is correct or not because I think it might be different from [Prove that any finite group $G$ of even order contains an element of order $2.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188519)

Here is my work,

take any $x \in t(G)$ now I consider $2$ cases where the order of $x$ is odd and even.

**Case 1:**
When the order of $x$ is odd, then it is clear that for any non-identity element $a \in\langle x\rangle$, $a \in t(G)$ by the Lagrange theorem. so it immediately follows $\langle x\rangle\setminus \{ e\} $ have even number of element.

**Case 2:**
When the order of $x$ is even ($|x|=2k$), we have only the $x^k$ has order $2$ in $\langle x\rangle$ and other elements also in $t(G)$ so it immediately follows $\langle x\rangle\setminus \{ x^k,e\} $ have even number of the element.

So by case $1$ and case $2$, we can conclude that $t(G)$ has an even number of elements.

Can anyone verify my answer?

Comment: $|t(G)|$ is always even, no matter $|G|$ is even or odd, isn't it?

Comment: @MathFail no this is valid for even order groups?

Comment: $G=Z_3, t(G)=\{1,2\}$ @puka

Comment: @puka In a group of odd order, identity is the only element which is inverse of itself.

Comment: @MathFail I didn't consider when $G$ is odd

Comment: @user977780 yes I know it. can you please tell me, is there anything wrong here?

Comment: You are overcounting, so your argument is at best incomplete. Note that you take all cyclic subgroups of $G$, bur some are contained in others. How do you know you aren't counting an odd number of elements an even number of times?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I got it thank you

Comment: Use `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 2):

Note this statement is true, no matter $|G|$ is even or odd. Whenever $g\in t(G)\Rightarrow g\neq g^{-1}$, then we have $g^{-1}\in t(G)$, because $(g^{-1})^{-1}\neq g^{-1}$. This implies $|t(G)|$ is even.

Comment: I got it. but really want to check my answer!

Comment: You are considering the cyclic group generated by $x$, but you need to prove $t(G)$ have even number of elements, you need to show how are they related?

Comment: Isn't it clearly related?

Comment: You are focusing on discussing the order of $x$ is even or odd, but it is NOT directly related to the order of $t(G)$ is even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $g\in t(G)$ so does $g^{-1}$. And, from definition they are different.
So, one can pair elements of $t(G)$.