# Prove a group of order 12 must have an element of order 2

Tags: group-theory

> Question: Prove that a group of order 12 must have an element of order 2.

I believe I've made great stride in my attempt.

By corollary to Lagrange's theorem, the order of any element $g$ in a group $G$ divides the order of a group $G$.

So, $ \left | g \right | \mid \left | G \right |$.
Hence, the possible orders of $g$ is $\left | g \right |=\left \{ 1,2,3,4,6,12 \right \}$

Suppose $\left | g \right |=12.$
Then, $g^{12}=\left ( g^{6} \right )^{2}=e.$
So, $\left | g^{6} \right |=2$

Using the above same idea and applying it to $\left | g \right |=\left \{ 6,4,2 \right \}$ and $\left | g \right |=1,$
we see that these elements g have order 2.

However, for $\left | g^{3} \right |$, the group $G$ does not require an element of order 2.

How can I take this attempt further?

Thanks in advance. Useful **hints** would be helpful.

Comment: In my humble opinion this is very close to being a duplicate of [this more general question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/42034/11619). It is a special case certainly. But in light of [a recent meta discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/23458/11619) I should not be the first to cast a vote. Also, it is possible that a trick special to order 12 exists.

Comment: Are you asking whether a group of order 12 must have an element of order 12, or order 2? I assume the latter, but there is discrepancy between the title and the statement in the text.

Comment: @Micapps Corrected!

Comment: **Hint:** [Cauchy's Theorem](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjcmdel-sXNAhXGqI8KHR9WAPgQFggvMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)&usg=AFQjCNH2dwif-zVmPJ8VvziX571mXi2Btw).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Hint:** Here is a simple proof idea that every group of even order must have an element of order $2$.

Pair every element in $G \backslash \{ e \}$ with its inverse. If all pairs consist of two different elements then $G \backslash \{ e \}$ would have an even number of elements.

What does it mean that $a=a^{-1}$?

> $a=a^{-1} \Leftrightarrow a^2=e$. And since $a \neq e$ we get that $ord(a)=2$.

Comment: It means that $a^{2}=e$

Comment: @Mathematicing exactly :) And you know that $a \neq e$ ....

Comment: Can the downvoter explain the mistake....

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, however, I might follow your rhetorical question with a spoiler marked-up answer (using ">!") so that your answer is complete even though the punchline is obscured.

Answer (score 6):

Approach without Sylow's theorem: By what you've shown, all you need to do is discount the possibility that all group elements have order $3$ or $1$. The only element with order $1$ is the identity. What can you say about a group that consists of the identity, and $11$ elements of order $3$?

Hint: the elements of order $3$ can be partitioned into pairs $\{g,h\}$ s.t. $h=g^2,g=h^2$.

Comment: A bit of clarification: Why is the identity element the only element with order 1? Certainly, e^{12}=e too.

Comment: The order of an element $g$ is by definition the least natural $n$ s.t. $g^n=e$. Thus $g$ has order $1$ iff $g^1=e \iff g=e$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
Consider the Sylow $2$-subgroups of $G,$ which have order $4.$

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is a Slow 2-subgroup?

Comment: he means Sylow subgroup

Comment: If they gave him this problem I doubt they've taught the Sylow theorems yet.

Comment: I've learnt Sylow theorem. In fact covered up till rings and fields. But I'm returning back to the earlier chapters as a revisions plus the fact that some theorem were not retained in my memory.

Comment: If you'e learnt Sylow theorems then odds are you've already learnt Cauchy theorem, too. This makes this question trivial.

Comment: Indeed, the proof by Arturo Magidin in the linked question by @JyrkiLahtonen is quite short and beautiful, and is the simplification of the standard proof of Cauchy theorem.