# Group of even order contains an element of order $2$ (Explanation)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am working on the problem:

> If G is a group of order 2n, show that the number of elements of G of order 2 is odd.

which **already has solution (in the link below), please explain the solution in that link**

[Group of even order contains an element of order 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42034/group-of-even-order-contains-an-element-of-order-2)

Comment: I think it's better to ask clarifications at the linked question instead of starting a new one.

Comment: how to ask such type of question

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos i ask explaination about the answer given in that question... i linked the question (which youcalled duplicate of in my question ... please read it completely. Thanks!}

Comment: @CloudJR Nothing that you wrote changes the fact that your question **is** a duplicate.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos but how can i clarify doubts in that answer? after all that question is active approximately 2 years ago. And author of that answer is not actively participated in SE(see his profile)

Comment: @CloudJR So, you should reproduce the answer here and then tell us which parts of it you don't understand.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin was last seen 7 hours ago, according to that profile. You can post comments to a posted answer asking for explanations.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma "I remain "gone for the foreseeable future" from math.SE, tex.SE, and meta.SE. Though I may very occasionally post a comment or an answer, these do not signify a desire to re-start my participation.

Please do not send me private e-mail to call my attention to comments, questions, or other matters related to those sites. Thank you. Also, as I no longer participate in those sites, I do not wish to be sent, by private e-mail, questions that you can just as well ask on those sites. I would have thought it was obvious, but apparently I need to say so explicitly." from his profile

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos okay , i will do it next time.. sorry for giving you trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the most popular answer defines a relation $x \sim y$ iff $x=y$ or $x=y^{-1}$.
You can check that this is indeed an equivalence relation and so we have the set of classes $C_i$, $i \in I$, which form a disjoint partition of $G$. Every class has size $1$ or $2$ (size $1$ iff $C_i = \{x\}$ with $x = x^{-1}$ or equivalently $x^2 = e$. If $x$ is not $e$ and does not have order $2$, it is in a class of size $2$, namely $\{x, x^{-1}\}$. There is at least one class of size $1$, namely $\{e\}$.

If $a$ is the number of classes of size $2$, it has $b:=|I|-a $ classes of size $1$, and $|G| = 2a + b$  and it follows that $b=|G|-2a$ is even, so $b \ge 2$ and so there is at least 1 class besides $\{e\}$ that has size $1$, and this is an element of order $2$.